# Import CSV with postgres geometry column as SF

Tags: r, postgresql, csv, postgis, r-sf

I have a csv file with a postgis geometry column. I want to import the csv in to R and export the file in to a postgres database. I'm trying to make the geometry column in to the proper postgis geometry data type. However, I keep getting this warning message:

"Warning message:
"no simple feature geometries present: returning a data.frame or tbl_df""

I've used:

```r
file <- st_read("name.csv", stringsAsFactors=F, geometry_column=geom) and

file <- fread("name.csv", headers=True)
file <- st_as_sf(file)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not load it directly to PostgreSQL with COPY or \copy?  If passing it through R causes problems, then....don't.

Comment: I'm doing some other editing in R prior to loading the table in to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer thanks to the r-sig-geo listserv

```
#1. convert the geometry strings to sf spatial objects:
newGeom = st_as_sfc(structure(as.character(file$geom), class = "WKB"),EWKB=TRUE)

#2. create a new spatial data frame with the new spatial objects as geometry
sdf = st_set_geometry(file, newGeom)

#3. (optional) drop the character format column
sdf$geom=NULL
```

Comment: Oh yes that was me answering! You might consider asking in future over on http://gis.stackexchange.com, the site for spatial and GIS questions.

Comment: Will do! Thank you for your answer.